# How to transfer attributes of a turtle to another in NetLogo?

Tags: inheritance, attributes, netlogo, turtle-graphics

I want to transfer attributes of a turtle to another. My aim is basically this;
I have created firm turtles, and if a firm bankrupts (if its net-worth is less than zero), I want this firm to copy attributes of a surviving firm(a firm that have positive net-worth)(firm will be randomly chosen). There are 50 firms, so first I should randomly select a surviving firm, and transfer its attributes to my bankrupt firm. (attributes like net-worth, output, etc)

I could only write a code to update my net-worth. Here it is;

```
to update-networth
  set networth networth + ( 1 - rd-fraction ) * profit
end
```

I would be glad if you can help me. I am stuck.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that the easiest way would be to pick some surviving turtle at random and have that firm `hatch` a new firm. Are there any attributes of the bankrupt firm that you want preserved (eg its location)? If so, you would need to assign them to the new firm, which just introduces the same problem from the other direction.

The direct way is something like the following:

```
to copy-attributes [from-firm to-firm]
  ask to-firm
  [ set attribute1 [attribute1] of from-firm
    set ....
  ]
end
```

Comment: No, I don't want to keep any attributes of bankrupt. I have looked for `hatch` and I think this may work well for me. Still could not match random firm with bankrupt firm though.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved, it may be helpful to someone else, hence I leave it here;

```
to update-networth ; firm 
  set networth networth + ( 1 - rd-fraction ) * profit
  if networth < 0
  [ ask firms [copy-attributes] ]
end

to copy-attributes 
  hatch-firms 1 [ set networth [networth] of one-of firms with [ networth ] > 0 ]  
end
```